# Compute the integral over the volume of a torus,

Tags: real-analysis, integration, geometry, multivariable-calculus, circles

In $\mathbb R^3$, let $C$ be the circle in the $xy$-plane with radius $2$ and the origin as the center, i.e.,

$$C= \Big\{ \big(x,y,z\big) \in \mathbb R^3 \mid x^2+y^2=4, \ z=0\Big\}.$$

Let $\Omega$ consist of all points $(x,y,z) \in \mathbb R^3$ whose distance to $C$ is at most $1$.  Compute 
$$\int_\Omega  \left|\,x\,\right|\,dx\,dy\,dz$$

So, with the help of erichan (see below), I now know that the volume is a solid torus.  But I am having trouble setting up the integration bounds.  As erichan had suggested, we consider a union of unit-spheres, all centered on points of the radius-$2$ circle.  Using spherical coordinates, I have this integral set up:

$$\int_0^\pi\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1 
\Big(\big|\,\left(r\cos \theta+2\right)\sin\phi \,\big| \,r^2 \sin\phi \Big) \, dr\, d\theta \,d\phi,$$

Where I parameterized the solid torus as:
$$
\begin{aligned}
x &= (r\cos \theta +2)\sin \phi \\
y &= (r\sin \theta +2)\sin\phi \\
z &= r\cos \phi 
\end{aligned}
$$
with Jacobian as $r^2\sin \phi$.

Is my setup ok?  I shifted $x$ and $y$ by two units. 
I'm not so sure about the parametrization of $z$ (should I leave it as it is normally?). 
And should I change the Jacobian factor?

I welcome any answers to this problem – I had previously requested just hints.
I am wondering whether there is a simpler way to compute this integral, using symmetry of the torus.

Thanks,

Comment: I added in some details - your parametrization is a little off as is, so I included the proper parametrization.

Answer (score 2):

So, you know it is a torus: then, your parametrization should be
$$
\begin{cases}
x = \big(\, 2 + r \cos \theta \, \big) \cos \phi \\
y = \big(\, 2 + r \cos \theta \, \big) \sin \phi \\
z = r \sin \theta
\end{cases}
$$
where $r \in [0,1]$ and $\theta, \phi \in [0, 2 \pi)$, and with jacobian
$$
\big|\,J\,\big|
=
\left| 
\begin{vmatrix}
\frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta} & \frac{\partial x}{\partial \phi} & \frac{\partial x}{\partial r} \\
%
\frac{\partial y}{\partial \theta} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial \phi} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial r} \\
%
\frac{\partial z}{\partial \theta} & \frac{\partial z}{\partial \phi} & \frac{\partial z}{\partial r} \\
\end{vmatrix}
\right|
=
\cdots
=
r \,\left( \,2 + r \cos \theta\,\right)
.
$$ 
Thus your integral becomes:
$$
\int_0 ^1 \int_0 ^{2 \pi} \int_0 ^{2 \pi} \big| 
\left(\,2 + r \cos \theta\,\right) \cos \phi \big| \, r \, ( \,2 + r \cos \theta\,) \, d \phi \, d \theta \, dr
$$
$$
=
\int_0 ^1 \int_0 ^{2 \pi} r\, \left( \,2 + r \cos \theta \,\right)^2 \, d \theta \, d r 
\int_0 ^{2 \pi} \big| \cos \phi \big| \, d \phi
$$
which simplifies to 
$$
\left[ \int_0 ^{2 \pi} \big| \cos \phi \big| \, d \phi \right] \cdot
\left[ 4 \int_0 ^1 r \, dr \int_0 ^{2 \pi} d \theta + 
4 \int_0 ^1 r^2 \, dr \int_0 ^{2 \pi} \cos \theta \, d \theta + 
\int_0 ^1 r^3 \, dr \int_0 ^{2 \pi} \cos ^2 \theta \, d \theta 
\right]
$$
which, while tedious, is rather trivial to compute.

Comment: @Vlad thanks for compensating for my clumsy fingers - it looks much better now.

Comment: Hi @izoec, thanks so much for this answer.  I'm reading up now on the parameterization of a torus.  What's the best way to understand it?  Is it more similar to spherical coordinates than to cylindrical coordinates?  And one more thing:  you have a term that integrates |cos| from 0 to 2pi - how can we treat the absolute value?  Should I integrate cos from -pi/2 to pi/2, and adding the integration of -cos from pi/2 to 3pi/2?  Thanks,

Comment: @LebronJames To understand the torus parametrization, think of it this way: You have a circle flat in the plane, which you are surrounding like a tube with another circle. $r$ is the radius of this second circle, so we want to expand $r$ from $0$ to $1$ here. The two angles each "parametrize" one of the circles - one angle tells you where you are on the flat circle in the plane, while at ever point on that circle, the other angle will parametrize another circle around it.

Comment: @LebronJames This picture kind of explains what I am trying to say: https://www.math.rutgers.edu/~greenfie/currentcourses/math291/gifstuff/torus_coords.gif

Comment: @LebronJames If you have done a very little bit of differential geometry in your multivariable calculus, you can understand this really, really well in terms of the moving frame / coordinate basis, using the tangent $\mathbf{T}$, normal $\mathbf{N}$, and binormal $\mathbf{B}$ vectors as your basis! But anyhow, think of it this way - in $z$, you want a circle, so you need $r$ and an angle, and in the $x$ and $y$, you need to do a circle with the other angle (NOT the $z$ angle!), but multiply by something that will give a circle in the z direction with that angle - so $\phi$ runs around the...

Comment: @LebronJames plane, while at every fixed $\phi$, we can run a circle about that along the $z$ axis using its angle $\theta$, and filling it in using $r$. Lastly (sorry to totally overwhelm with the length of this!), to do the integral of $|\cos|$ is actually very straightforward: break $[0, 2\pi)$ up into the sections where $\cos$ is positive and do $\int \cos$ on that, and add it to the integral $\int (-\cos)$ where it is taken over the part of the domain where $\cos$ is negative (and thus $- \cos$ is positive.

Comment: Hi @izoec, thanks so much for your answer and additional comments - you were super helpful.  I spent today reading up some more on spherical coordinates to try to make a connection between it and the parameterization of the torus.  (Spherical coordinates, it turns out, is more "polar" than cylindrical coordinates.)  I think I'm ready to compute this integral now - like you said, the computation is the easy part.  Thanks again!  Have a great night :-)

Comment: Hey @LebronJames, No problem - I am glad it started making sense, and that I could help!

Answer (score 1):

Since you only want hints...

For each point on the circle of radius $2$ consider a solid sphere of radius $1$. Now consider the union of all these spheres. What do you get?

Comment: That's so cool, @erichan...

Comment: I seem to get a bunch of radius 1 disks, but all going in a circular direction to cover the radius-2 circle.  So is it like a cylinder, but going in a circle?

Comment: They are spheres, not disks.

Comment: You get what is called a torus

Comment: Oh, gosh, that was my first guess but didn't want to say it, since this is preparation for an advanced calc exam, not topology.  So, I kept trying to force something cylindrical to come out ...

Comment: How can I integrate this solid torus, @erichan?  A wild guess would be to compute the volume of the radius-3 sphere, minus the volume of the unit sphere...

Comment: Sorry, we're not  computing the volume of this torus, but instead we're integrating |x| over the solid torus...

Comment: I'm going to go for the computation now, in spherical coordinates.

Comment: Hi @erichan, if you're willing to post a solution now, I'd welcome it very much :-).  I just edited my post to show my parametrization work, if you want to comment on it, too.  Thanks!